# fail to update jdk1.7.0_45 in raspberry pi

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, xming

I'm developing the TV Scoreboard app with the use of window laptop and raspberry pi.
I'm using the putty to have socket connection.

Before that it request to state the X11 server variable, so I have installed the Xming server in my window laptop and fixed to `localhost:0.0.0.0`

But JFLauncher keep pop up the message to install the newest Java Runtime.
So I think the latest and suitable one should be `jre 1.7.0_45`.

I have download the e`jre-7u45-fcs-b15-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-client_headless-26_sep_2013`

```
 mkdir java
    cd java
    tar zxvf *.gz
```

after unpack, I remove the rar file.

```
./bin/java -version
```

it show the latest version but if I just

```
java -version
```

it show the old version detail.

what should I do to update it to the latest version?
Any mistake for my steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but if i just java -version it show the old version detail.

When you run this command from your command line, the `PATH` environment variable is what the shell will evaluate to determine how to disambiguate your command.  If you don't ensure that the new java binary location is in your `PATH`, and has a higher precedence than the old one, then the shell has no way of knowing to execute your new java.

Try the following:

```
$which java //tells you which java command the shell will execute
$echo $PATH //shows you what directories are in your path
$export PATH=/my/new/java/bin/directory:$PATH //set your new java into the PATH env
$java -version
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) tutorial on setting PATH.

Comment: how do i set it?
java/jre/ejre1.7.0_45 is under user "pi".

Comment: you set your PATH using the export PATH=.... command.  you should read some tutorials on setting the PATH variable

Comment: Thank you. I have successfully update the java version by giving the right path.